# PHP if else with a database

Tags: php

I have the error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant KATEGORIE - assumed 'KATEGORIE' in C:ThisFile on line 13

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM artikel ORDER BY datum DESC";     
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<a class='article-header'>$row[TITEL]</a>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a class='article-autor'>geschrieben von $row[AUTOR] am $row[DATUM]</a>";
        echo "<p>$row[NACHRICHT]</p>";
        echo "<a href='images/face.png' data-lightbox='image-1' ><img class='article-picture' src='images/face.png'></a>";

        if($row[KATEGORIE]==1){ <!-- Line 13 -->
            echo "Kategorie: <a href='index.php?category=1'>Karten</a>";
        }

        echo "<hr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: first change the $row[KATEGORIE] to $row['KATEGORIE']

Comment: Thanks! :) This answer is perfect too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace

```
if($row[KATEGORIE]==1){
```

to

```
if($row['KATEGORIE']==1){
```

if you use direct in capital/without quotes (KATEGORIE) without $ will be consider as constant. not as an array index
if you use with quoting like

```
"<a class='article-autor'>geschrieben von $row[AUTOR]"
```

will be consider as an array index("AUTOR" will be an array index)

Comment: It doesn't matter if the key is capitelized or not. With quotes it's string, without them constant.

Comment: If there's no constant with that name it will silently stringify it

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Better rename the database attribute to "kategorie", "autor"?